# Toggling Google Map layers on and off

Tags: jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am building a custom Google Map (http://www.southdevonaonb.org.uk/cordialemapping/) and I am having a problem toggling layers on and off.

I am using a simple checkbox in the html - for example:

```
Parish boundary line <input type="checkbox" id="layer100" onclick="toggleLayer(100)"  checked><br /> 
Letterbox locations and results <input type="checkbox" id="layer0" onclick="toggleLayer(0)" checked><br />
Landscape challenges <input type="checkbox" id="layer1" onclick="toggleLayer(1)" checked><br />
```

and the following JavaScript:

```
var geocoder;
var map; 
var marker;
var layers = [];

function initialize() {
geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder ();
var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng (50.31697, -3.670807);
var myOptions = {
  zoom: 10,
  center: latlng,
  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    }
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-container"),
    myOptions);
  marker = new google.maps.Marker({map:map});

  layers[100] = new google.maps.KmlLayer('http://www.southdevonaonb.org.uk/cordialemapping/kmzdata/100.kml', {preserveViewport: true});
  layers[200] = new google.maps.KmlLayer('http://www.southdevonaonb.org.uk/cordialemapping/kmzdata/200.kml', {preserveViewport: true});
  layers[300] = new google.maps.KmlLayer('http://www.southdevonaonb.org.uk/cordialemapping/kmzdata/boundaryline.kml', {preserveViewport: true});




  layers[0] = new google.maps.KmlLayer('http://www.southdevonaonb.org.uk/cordialemapping/kmzdata/beta0.kml', {preserveViewport: true});
  layers[1] = new google.maps.KmlLayer('http://www.southdevonaonb.org.uk/cordialemapping/kmzdata/beta1.kml', {preserveViewport: true});
  layers[2] = new google.maps.KmlLayer('http://www.southdevonaonb.org.uk/cordialemapping/kmzdata/beta2.kml', {preserveViewport: true});
  layers[10] = new google.maps.KmlLayer('http://www.southdevonaonb.org.uk/cordialemapping/kmzdata/beta10.kml', {preserveViewport: true});
  layers[11] = new google.maps.KmlLayer('http://www.southdevonaonb.org.uk/cordialemapping/kmzdata/beta11.kml', {preserveViewport: true});
  layers[46] = new google.maps.KmlLayer('http://www.southdevonaonb.org.uk/cordialemapping/kmzdata/holbeton.kml', {preserveViewport: true});
  for (var i = 1; i < layers.length; i++) {
    layers[i].setMap(map);
  }
    }
function codeAddress () {
    var address = document.getElementById ("address").value;
    geocoder.geocode ( { 'address': address}, function(results, status)  {
    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK)  {
        map.setCenter(results [1].geometry.location);
        marker.setPosition(results [1].geometry.location);
        map.setZoom(14);
        } 
    else {
        alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
            }
}); 
}

function toggleLayer(i) {
  if(layers[i].getMap() === null) {
    layers[i].setMap(map);
  }
  else {
    layers[i].setMap(null);
  }
}
  google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

You will see from the script that I haven't yet added all the layers in the list on the page linked above and that I have styled the menu in tabs using the jQuery Accordian Plugin.

The layers that I have added so far toggle on and off okay, but the problem I am getting is that when the page is loaded sometimes a layer will show and other times it is hidden and will require the checkbox to be ticked several times before it will appear.

I am trying to find a solution to fix this so that the map page will first load with the checkboxes unchecked and the layers hidden. Then as a checkbox is ticked the layer will toggle on and then off again when the checkbox is unticked?

Answer (score 1):

You're missing a semi colon after setting the myOptions variable.

I'm updating this with more problems I've found with your code.

Your for loop that sets the map to the layers is incorrect. The layers array has a length of 301 but that's because you manually set an item at index 300. You can't blindly iterate over the layers array when there are gaps between array indexes that contain values. If you really want to do a for loop then you need to safety check your indexes like so

```
for (var i = 1; i < layers.length; i++) {
    if (typeof layers[i] != 'undefined') {
        layers[i].setMap(map);
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, it's missing, but javascript doesn't require semicolons.

Comment: Not necessarily true, I've seen instances where missing semi colons cause IE to freak out.

Comment: Thanks for your help... I tried adding the check you suggested, but then the map wouldn't load...?

Comment: Do you have the code I suggested running on a page that's publicly accessible? You should be using a javascript debugger like the one in Chrome, it will tell you where the errors are happening.

Answer (score 0):

Although I haven't found the documentation for this, in my experience, the Google Maps API won't show more than 5 KML layers on a map at once (this is similar to the restriction on FusionTablesLayers, which is documented [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/layers#FusionTablesLimits)).

If you don't want your layers showing up on load, then don't call `setMap` on them in your `initialize` function.  Then, only the layers that have been 'checked' (and been added to the map in the `toggleLayer` function) will show up on the map.

You should add a note that adding more than 5 layers to the map won't work, or you could add code to keep track of the last 5 added layers, and upon adding a 6th will remove the first (least recently added) layer.

```
var addedlayers = [];
function toggleLayer(i) {
    if (layer.getMap() === null) {
        addedlayers.push(i);
        if(addedlayers.length > 5) {
            var ejected = addedlayers.shift();
            layers[ejected].setMap(null);
            document.getElementById("layer" + ejected).checked = false;
        }
        layers[i].setMap(map);
    } else {
        layers[i].setMap(null);
        addedlayers.splice(addedlayers.indexOf(i)) //remove from addedlayers
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Jeff-Meadows for your help... I'm unsure what you mean by not calling setMap on the layers in the initialize function? Do you mean changing  layers[i].setMap(map); to null? I also like the idea of restricting the number of active layers - where would I need to insert the function that you suggest?

Comment: This line of code: `layers[i].setMap(map);` adds the layer to the map.  If you omit that bit of code, the layers will start out "hidden".  You already have a function `toggleLayer` - I was suggesting that you replace that function with the one in my answer.  Hope it helps!